# Как можно оптимизировать\сократить функцию (объединение двух циклов)

Tags: c

Есть функция копирования с текстового файла в другой функции main. Загвоздка в том, что нужно объединить два цикла while, но никак не могу допереть как именно.

```
    void Search(FILE* Reading, char* strings)
{
    while (fgets(strings, 150, Reading)) 
    {
        if (strstr(strings, " main ") || strstr(strings, " main(") || strstr(strings, " main\n"))
            break;
    }
}

void Copy(FILE * Reading, FILE * Writing, int* L, int* R, char* strings) 
{
    int tmp;
    fputs(strings, Writing);
    if (strchr(strings, '{'))
        * L += 1;
    else {
        while (strchr(fgets(strings, 150, Reading), '{') == NULL)
            fputs(strings, Writing);
        fputs(strings, Writing);
        *L += 1;
    }

    while (*L != *R) {
        tmp = fgetc(Reading);
        if (tmp == '{')
            * L += 1;
        if (tmp == '}')
            * R += 1;
        fputc(tmp, Writing);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Неплохо было бы сказать, для начала, а что Вы собственно желаете получить? Мы должны угадать?

Если моя догадка верна, то Вам нужно сделать две вещи:

1. Скопировать исходный файл
2. Посчитать количество правых и левых фигурных скобок.

Я прав? Тогда зачем нужна функция *Search* ? В приведённом куске текста она нигде не используется!

Смысл первого цикла остался для меня совершенно туманным...
Вы пытаетесь проверить баланс скобок?

Для этого есть очень простой приём, который называется "уровень вложенности". 
Заводим переменную *int level;* Каждый раз, встречая левую скобку - увеличиваем её, встречая правую - уменьшаем.  Если она станет отрицательной - ошибка. Если в конце обработки она не равна нулю - ошибка.

А про оптимизацию (!!!) пока говорить рано... :-)

Comment: есть текстовый файл с программой.нужно с него скопировать в другой файл функцию мейн. search ищет обьявление функции.

Comment: и в первом цикле,ищем 1 скобку если после main был ентер либо несколько ентер

Comment: @SvyatVasik - *скопировать в другой файл функцию мейн* - очень хорошо.  Функция *search* нашла строку, с которой начинается ф-ция *main()*. Надо просто скопировать остаток файла, начиная с текущей строки. Зачем тогда вся оставшаяся часть Вашей программы?  Если предполагается, что ф-ция *main()* может быть в средине файла, тогда заведите перемнную *level* и считайте в ней уровень вложенности скобок (как я написал в ответе). Как только *level==0*, значит ф-ция *main()* кончилась и можно прекращать копирование.